# Add date and text trough conditional formatting?

Tags: excel, date, text, formatting, conditional-statements

Suppose I have empty cells `A1:F1`
Everyday people have to sign a cell with name and todays date.

For example, cell `A1` will contain "Andrew Peterson 1/8-20" .. the next day cell `B1` will get signed with "Joshua Jackson 2/8-20"

I wonder if it's possible to sign a cell, like `A1` with "JJ", and trough conditional formatting or something else, convert the "JJ" to "Joshua Jackson" + todays date, still in cell `A1`.. And if "AP" is written the cell will show Andrew's name + date.

I know how to do it with VBA, but I'm not allowed to save the file as .xlsm at my workplace.
Is it even possible to it without VBA?

Comment: No, you need VBA or some other programmatic approach to do this.

Comment: If you have to keep the signature in `A1` then I can't think of a solution without VBA or circular referencing.